# How to redirect GET response from API to another page

Tags: html

I want to know how I'm supposed to redirect to another page while using an API to get data there at the same time

My situation:
- a product page which list all the products retrieved from API (product.html)
- A JSON API which GET data from the product ID (api/products?id=?)
- a product page which describe individual product (indiv_product.html)

What I know:
Redirecting the product.html to indiv_product.html when a product is selected and clicked.

What I do not know:
Calling the API in product.html because I need the ID to be specified there, and getting the response in indiv_product.html so I can populate the page with the data from the API